# Rust/Webassembly/wasm-bindgen - getting values from `js_sys' Promise

Tags: promise, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm playing with `wasm-bindgen` ( https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen ), just out of curiosity.

While playing with the `Navigator` (`web_sys` crate) I stumbled upon this method:

https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.36/web_sys/struct.MediaDevices.html#method.enumerate_devices

it returns a `Result<Promise, JsValue>`..now, I'm new to Rust, and my question is how can I fetch the value of the `Promise`?

How the `Closure::wrap` works? 
How to use it with [then](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.36/js_sys/struct.Promise.html#method.then) method to fetch the results?

I wonder if someone could be so kind to explain me how to deal with [Promise](https://docs.rs/js-sys/0.3.36/js_sys/struct.Promise.html)

Here an example that returns a `Promise`:

```rust
let window = web_sys::window().expect("no global `window` exists");
let navigator = window.navigator();

if let Ok(devs) = navigator.media_devices() {
   if let Ok(prom) = devs.enumerate_devices() {
        //..??? how to list all devices 
   }
}
```

All the best,
Luca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [official documentation available on the wasm-bindgen site](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/js-promises-and-rust-futures.html).

In short, you can use `wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture::from(promise).await?` to retrieve the result of the promise and continue working with the usual Rust `async` functionality.

Comment: thanks for the hint @milgner, I tried, but I'm not able to enumerate all the devices, I'll try to scan all the examples looking for something similiar.